Are there any cruelty-free weedkillers or other cruelty-free methods for de-weeding driveways?
I need to de-weed a driveway and paths that are completely ravaged by weeds. I am not able to do this repeatedly and so just digging the weeds out does not seem to be a good option especially given a dodgy knee.
I am worried that using a normal weed-killer, salt, acetic acid or a weed-burner will kill or harm various insects, bugs, worms and so forth. Is thee a cruelty free way to achieve this?

Although not vegan, having an actual goat eat the weeds could be argued to be non-cruel.

I do not know about acetic acid, but salt will remain in the ground "forever", and make that soil infertile for a very long time. Although a solution, salt should be a last resort IMO. Why not use a trimmer and cut the weed very short? With the trimmer you stand tall, and no damage to the knee, I guess (I never used a trimmer). If you cannot do it yourself, maybe get someone's help. Either a kind neighbor (even a child can do that kind of job), or a for-some-profit de-weeder.
